# Indefinite amount of generic types in template?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to make a custom print function that takes any amount of arguments and prints them all on new lines.

In javascript, the document.write and console.log functions can do this because javascript stores all arguments in an array. To my knowledge, c++ doesn't do this and can't because of type restrictions.

So is there a proper way to do this in c++? Take any amount of arguments, regardless of type, and print them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D), similar to [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf), but you will still need to know the types of the arguments and how many there are to be able to access them properly.

A better approach would probably be to do something similar to how the << operator was overloaded for `ostream` or use a chainable function. You will in the end still be limited to types (or supertypes with virtual functions) you know about.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is with the new C+11 standard. Please take a look at this article :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template

There is a pretty nice example also you can use as a starter.

Answer (score 1):

From Bjarne himself:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#variadic-templates

His code as of today:

```
void printf(const char* s)  
{
    while (s && *s) {
        if (*s=='%' && *++s!='%')   // make sure that there wasn't meant to be more arguments
                                    // %% represents plain % in a format string
            throw runtime_error("invalid format: missing arguments");

        std::cout << *s++;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>      // note the "..."
void printf(const char* s, T value, Args... args)   // note the "..."
{
    while (s && *s) {
        if (*s=='%' && *++s!='%') { // a format specifier (ignore which one it is)
            std::cout << value;     // use first non-format argument
            return printf(++s, args...);    // "peel off" first argument
        }
        std::cout << *s++;
    }
    throw std::runtime error("extra arguments provided to printf");
}
```